# solr get in which field the match was found so to seperate the result set

Tags: django, solr

I am new to solr, i have a schema as follows

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="slug" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="location" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="city" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="area" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="featured" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="facilities" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="type_of_venue" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />...
```

there are many other fields which are used only for display of data on results page but only these fields are used to query data

these is used to index venue details in solr, after indexing i use the following query according to the user input in search box to find the search string in title,description,location,city,area,facilities and type of venue

my query is

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/venue/select?q=title:('+data+')^1000+OR+description:('+data+')^10+OR+location:('+data+')^100+OR+city:('+data+')^100+OR+area:('+data+')^100+OR+facilities:('+data+')^50+OR+type_of_venue:('+data+')^100&hl=true&hl.fl=title
```

i have highlighting on so it shows me highlighted results for matches found in which field and i show it on result page.

what i want to achieve here is make two separate result set one is close match which should be results which are found in only title and the full search string found in title and the next will be close match where the searched string will be found in other fields other than title.
i read about debug query but it gives an explanation and not the exact field which i can put a check on in code to distinguish between the sets, i am using django with solr

the main purpose behind this is that if the search string is mostly found in title then i know its the name of a venue and display the related search array in different format or else if it is mostly found in location then i know the user is searching for a location and display a map along with the location details

thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I understand your question completely but it looks like you will need to run two different searches (probably best option). Without a second query: If you want to separate the results maybe post processing the results with `if data in result.title` will work. The boost `^1000` should bring the title matches to the top (you may want to use a larger number like 20000 to be safe since you are boosting other fields and a multi field match might exceed a title match only).

Comment: @Dotcomly i had used two different queries initially but then changed it to one, i will do some post processing on the data to separate the two sets was wondering if i could do it in solr itself, the number boost to 20000 is a very good suggestion. thanks